# Angular conditional validators based on values change

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I am looking to achieve a required field for either email or phone input field.

For example, when an email input is empty, then phone is a required field.On the other hand, when a phone input is empty, then email is a required field.

In my following code, there is an error show in console "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null"

I have tried split both as an individual function, yet I got another error message of saying “RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded”.

```
this.contactForm.get(["email", "phone"]).valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
        let emailValue: string = data.email;
        let phoneValue: string = data.phone;
        if (emailValue == "") {
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]);
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].updateValueAndValidity();
        } else {
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].clearValidators();
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].updateValueAndValidity();
        }

        if (phoneValue == "") {
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.email]);
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].updateValueAndValidity();
        } else {
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].clearValidators();
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].updateValueAndValidity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should create a customer validator and pass the values that you need to check (e.a emailValue and phoneValue), see following example:https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular

Comment: You are misusing the `FormGroup.prototype.get` API. It accepts an array of paths to access nested properties, not to return multiple controls. Furthermore, if it did return multiple controls, it would have to return them in an array or object which would not have a  `valueChanges` method. You need to rethink things.

Answer (score 0):

As you know you can use `required` validator in the html directly. So, make it computable and add the condition. Like

```
<input ... [required]="!contactForm.get('phone').value.length"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have managed to solve the issue by passing an array of contactForm as json.

Access each element as data.email and data.phone to get its specific value.

Most importantly, modify updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true }) such that it won't trigger a range error of maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
this.contactForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.email == "" || data.email == null) {
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]);
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        } else {
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].clearValidators();
            this.contactForm.controls["phone"].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        }

        if (data.phone == "" || data.phone == null) {
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.email]);
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        } else {
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].clearValidators();
            this.contactForm.controls["email"].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
        }
    });
```